# clientScript() function in testcafe isn't working on all pages

Tags: javascript, testcafe, clientscript

According to Testcafe's documentation, I should be able to inject a clientScript into all pages: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402843/guides/advanced-guides/inject-client-scripts#add-client-scripts-to-all-tests

I currently have it set up to inject this script so that it can dismiss notifications that pop up in our application which overlay buttons that we need to interact with.

```html
const notifications_div = document.querySelector('.notifications')

if (notifications_div) {
  // Creates the MutationObserver and triggers the callback
  const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {

    // Checks to see if the style is set to 'block'
    if (notifications_div.style.display == 'block') {
      // Set the dismiss button to a variable each time since the previous will no longer exist.
      let dismiss_button = document.querySelector("a[data-turbo-method='delete']")
      // Click the dismiss button; Timeout is needed to avoid race condition errors.
      setTimeout(() => { dismiss_button.click(); }, 3000);
      // Hide the notifications_div again since it never truly goes away; Timeout is needed to avoid race condition errors.
      setTimeout(() => { notifications_div.style.display = 'none'; }, 3000);
    }

  })
  // Starts the observation of the notifications_div and checks for a change on 'style'
  mutationObserver.observe(notifications_div, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    attributeFilter: ['style']
  })
}
```

When I run this code in the console and then trigger a notification, it works just fine. When I run a testcafe suite I still end up seeing notifications (that asynchronously pop up), cover the button that I need to interact with, and never close.

When does the code actually get injected? Is it every page load?

**Video of the script working fine via the console:** https://www.loom.com/share/1a5b96d054a345748e4f018bc56af413

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Client Script injection should work even after a new page is loaded. The following code snippet demonstrates that the script is injected:

```
fixture`f`
    .page`http://example.com`;

const clientScript = `
    console.log('location: ' + window.location.href);
`;

test
('My test', async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('http://google.com');
    await t.debug();
})
    .clientScripts({ content: clientScript });
```

If this code does not help, please create a separate issue in the TestCafe official repository using the following template and share an example where the problem is reproduced: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml.